# Crontab not executing CURL command in linux

Tags: bash, curl, cron, chmod

I created bash script and tried to execute it manually.then it's working properly.
After that I created crontab and set it to execute after every 5 minutes.but it's not working.

here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/api/refresh >> /var/www/my/log/cron/log
exit 0
```

After creating this shell file I granted permissions using

```
chmod -x /etc/cron.my/refresh.sh
```

Here is the code of crontab

```
*/5 * * * * /etc/cron.my/refresh.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't granted execution permission to the script, in fact, you have tried to remove it. You should have written: `chmod a+x /etc/cron.my/refresh.sh`

Also, restart the cron service after the modification.

Comment: Have you restarted the cron service as well?

Comment: ,It's my mistake.now it's working.thanks alot for your help :)